# Reduce 3D effect from Angular Material Card?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have [this layout](https://lakshyalife-5cb8a.firebaseapp.com/home) designed in Angular-Material. Is it possible to `reduce the 3D effect` by reducing the z-index. Eventually narrow it down to following effect.

```
    <div style="border: 1px">
        ... box content
    </div>
```

I tried manipulating z-index of the container class, but I receive invalid property value error.

```
.mat-drawer-container
{ 
    z-index: 1 
}
```

P.S. Unfortunately can't remove material card & replace it with Div as layout breaks. Hence looking for a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `mat-elevation-z{X}` to your card class, where `{X}` goes from 1 to 24 and represents how raised it is compared to z=0;

[Official docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation)